# Which should be used to GROUP BY: text fields or numeric fields?

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

So, I am currently enrolled in a Database Concepts course (yes, I am a noob) and the professor posed the question: "In a `GROUP BY` clause, for example `GROUP BY xxxx`, should the `xxxx` on which we’re grouping be a text field or a numeric field?"

I am very confused by this question, because it is possible to `GROUP BY` either text or numeric fields.  I have tried both and received no errors.  I realize that it typically makes more sense to `GROUP BY` text fields because, for instance, you would want to know how many products have a `price` greater than `50.00`.  The reverse of this would likely be unnecessary.  Is there a "best practice" rule that I am missing here?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It may have been specific to the situation that your professor mentioned—perhaps the intent was to group by a particular field.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The correct answer is . . . "xxxx should be whatever is needed to resolve the problem at hand."

You should review the notes or talk to the professor to understand the context of that statement.  As you clearly understand, a SQL query can aggregate by numeric, character, or date/time columns -- as well as various other data types.  From a *functional* perspective, all are supported.

There might be a bit of a performance advantage to using numbers.  This is an artifact that sorting on fixed-width fields is often faster (marginally) than sorting on variables length fields.  I sincerely doubt that your professor is referring to this, however.

Comment: Thank you for the reply! What you said makes sense and helps affirm what I was thinking. I just wanted to be sure that I wasn't missing some "unwritten rule". I will get with my professor on Monday and pin down just what she meant. Thanks again!